# Hide and show button in each click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons. In one case the first button is 'disable' and in another case it's 'enable', but in one button no show with style `display: none`.

I use jQuery for in the first case. I click over the enable button and show the disable button. The next time the disable button hide and show other time the button enable.

The script doesn't work correctly because it only works one time in each case and finally stops.

I have link for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/onfynvfk/5/

The script is this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".but_1").click(function() {
        jQuery(".but_1").hide("2"); 
        jQuery(".but_2").show("1").delay(1, function() {    
            jQuery(".but_2").hide("2");  
        });
        jQuery(".but_2").hide("2");     
        jQuery(".but_1").show("2");  
    });
});
```

The buttons these :

```
<input name="enviar" type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="c_input_submit" class="but_2" style="display:none;" value="Send Hide" />
<input name="enviar" type="submit" id="c_input_submit" class="but_1" value="Send Normal" />
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry but the link to js fiddle no right i put other time , sorry

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: I quickly put this together, it may point you in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/o9wgxz0z/

Answer (score 1):

Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/1zv3ty0u/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".but_1").click(function() {

        $(".but_1").hide(); 
        $(".but_2").show();
    });

    $(".but_2").click(function(){
        $(".but_2").hide();
        $(".but_1").show();
    });
});
```

And html:

```
<input name="enviar" type="submit" id="c_input_submit" class="but_2 
style="display:none;" value="Send Hide" />

<input name="enviar" type="submit" id="c_input_submit" 
class="but_1" value="Send Normal" />
```

By the way, `$()` is equal to `jQuery()` and the former is typically used to improve code readability.

Comment: The problem it´s i need change from normal to disable in one cycle for show other time the button enabled , show normal button , click show disable button 3 seconds and show enableb and if click other time and enabled button repit the cycle , regards

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqf0qhp6/

If you have a class in your css, named hide, you can do this very easily:

```
$('.but_1, .but_2').click(function(){
    $('.but_1, .but_2').toggleClass('hide');
 });
```

and your hide class would simply: {display:none;} and start out attached to one of the buttons (whichever you want to be default state).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be closer to your requirments:

```
<input class="js-btn-one" value="Button One" type="button" />
<input class="js-btn-two" value="Button Two" type="button" />

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.js-btn-two').hide();

    $('.js-btn-one').click(function()
    {
        $('.js-btn-two').show();
        if($('.js-btn-two').is(":visible"))
        {
            $('.js-btn-two').prop( "disabled", false );
        }

        $(this).prop( "disabled", true );
    });

    $('.js-btn-two').click(function()
    {
        $('.js-btn-one').prop( "disabled", false );
        $(this).prop( "disabled", true);
    });
});
```